# Angular.js ui-router module route helper provider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am very new to Angular.js. I'm following John Papa's angular style guide, and I do not understand this section about a route helper provider (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#routing).

I am using generator-ng-poly (https://github.com/dustinspecker/generator-ng-poly#route) because it seemed to closely follow the preferred style guide.

My question comes in at the difference in route handling. the generator-ng-poly uses a configuration with $stateProvider to set the route for each module. The John Papa style guide uses a route helper provider that seems to collect the routes for each module in a run function, but there isn't any explanation about the reason, or the benefit of setting it up like that. I have tried using both ways, and they both seem to work. The configure version feels like a simpler approach. Can someone explain if and why the route helper provider is a better approach? Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question?